# boto3 error for creating stack instances with "deployment targets"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm using service managed permission to create_stack_instances for an OU, filtered by intersection of a list of accounts and when i run the command, it gives me an error, Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code here?

1. error via cli

   Parameter validation failed:
   Unknown parameter in DeploymentTargets: "AccountFilterType", must be one of: Accounts, AccountsUrl, OrganizationalUnitIds
2. error via lambda

   [ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
   Unknown parameter in DeploymentTargets: "AccountFilterType", must be one of: Accounts, AccountsUrl, OrganizationalUnitIds
3. lambda code:

   def add_stack_to_stackset(StackSetName, accountid):

   ```
    response = CF.create_stack_instances(
        StackSetName=StackSetName,
        DeploymentTargets={
            'OrganizationalUnitIds': ['ou-blah'],
             'Accounts': [accountid],
            'AccountFilterType': 'INTERSECTION'
        },
        Regions=['us-east-1']
    )
    op_id = response['OperationId']
    return op_id
   ```
4. cli code

   aws cloudformation create-stack-instances --stack-set-name demo --deployment-targets OrganizationalUnitIds=ou-blah,Accounts=12345,AccountFilterType=INTERSECTION --regions us-east-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `ValidationErrors` are just bugs or occur when you are using an old version of boto3 - for example, in the [newest version of boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack_instances) `INTERSECTION` is a valid parameter (if you are using this version then it is a bug...).

You can always disable request validation:

> [parameter_validation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html)
>
> Disable parameter validation (default is true,
> parameters are validated). This is a Boolean value that is either true
> or false. Whenever you make an API call using a client, the parameters
> you provide are run through a set of validation checks, including (but
> not limited to) required parameters provided, type checking, no
> unknown parameters, minimum length checks, and so on. Typically, you
> should leave parameter validation enabled.

Comment: This was the issue. I was told by someone at boot to just add a lambda layer with the latest boto3 and I once I did that, worked.

Comment: This is what i did and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but with aws cli. Upgrading to aws cli v2 resolved it. So I'd suspect the same problem with boto3. Using latest version should get this working.